# .htaccess to rewrite a get variable to something more elegant

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have just finished writing a new site. It is a simple blog. The only advice I have received from my readers is that I should consider changing the www.example.com/?page=3 to something like www.example.com/1.

How should I go about writing this rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your URLs have a common pattern and parts of the externally used URL can directly be mapped onto the internally used URL while retaining a uniquely identifiable URL (like your URL probably does), you can do something like this with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will rewrite a request of `/12345` internally to `/?page=12345`.

Otherwise, if there isn’t a pattern or the mapping is not trivial, you will probably need to specify each case like:

```
RewriteEngin on
RewriteRule ^foo$ /?page=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^bar$ /?page=2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^baz$ /?page=3 [L,QSA]
```

You could also just pass the request to your PHP file and do the mapping in there.